# delete XML node, keep original

Tags: xml, apache-flex, flash, e4x

I need to delete some nodes from an XML variable and I want to keep the original intact.
So I pass the XML to a new variable and delete the nodes from that one but the original changes with it.

Is there a way to protect the XML from the original variable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you want to clone the xml, not just set another variable reference to it.

try `var xmlbackup:XML = xml.copy();`

Answer (score 0):

I think that next code do the job too:

```
var newXML : XML = new XML(oldXML);
```